# Possible to combine glob sort w/ alternation in zsh?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

Looking for a shell-only[1] way to take this list of dirs:

```
foo1.1
foo1.10
foo1.10/bar
foo1.2
foo1.3
foo1.3/bar
foo1.4
foo1.5
foo1.5/bar
foo1.6
foo1.7
foo1.8
foo1.9
foo2.1
```

And return it sorted numerically, with the subdirs showing up right after their parent:

```
foo1.1
foo1.2
foo1.3
foo1.3/bar
foo1.4
foo1.5
foo1.5/bar
foo1.6
foo1.7
foo1.8
foo1.9
foo1.10
foo1.10/bar
foo2.1
```

`(*|*/bar)(n)` is rejected as a bad pattern, while `*/{,bar}(n)` expands to `*/(n) ~/bar(n)` so the subdirs show up at the end.

[1] I need this to be able to work on a wide variety of systems, so using GNU sort's -V or GNU ls's -v or the like won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it in two steps: list, then sort.

```
dirs=(* */bar)
dirs=(${(on)dirs})
```

This relies on `/` being sorted before any suffix of an existing directory, so it won't work if you have directories with names like `foo1.3-qux` (it would be sorted between `foo1.3` and `foo1.3/bar`. Since all the files are directories, you could work around that with a temporary `/` suffix, if it's ok to have `foo1.3-qux` sorted before `foo1.3`:

```
dirs=(*/ */bar)
dirs=(${${(on)dirs}%/})
```

For more robustness you can temporarily replace the `/` characters by a null byte, which is both guaranteed to be sorted before any other (at least in the C locale) and not to appear in a file name.

```
dirs=(* */bar)
dirs=(${${(on)${dirs//\//$'\0'}}//$'\0'//})
```